# Logic Apps Video Indexer Connector

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-video-indexer

I have been working on creating a logic app for indexing videos.
I followed the documentation, creating a blob storage, the 2 flows etc..
When I run the flow, I get an error at the Get Video Indexer Token connector.
I have tried creating the api through Azure Media Service, and also the Video Indexer Api site itself.
I also tried to search google for solutions/examples/matching problems, without luck.

The documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/logic-apps-connector-tutorial

[Video Indexer Access Token Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f6XD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some test, when we sign in the [Video Indexer](https://www.videoindexer.ai/) page with AAD account, we can find a "Trial" beside the account name.

[image]

So please change the location to "trial" but not "northeurope" in your logic app.
[image]

After that, we can get the access token successfully.
[image]